# Show that a set is uncountable.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $B$ be the set of all sequences cosisting of digits $7$, $8$, and $9$. Show that $B$ is uncountable.

Here is my attempt.

Assume to the contrary that $B$ is countable. Then there exists a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $B$. Let $\psi : \mathbb{N} \to B$ be a bijective function, so that it is defined by
$$\psi(\mathbb{N})=\{\psi(1),\psi(2),\psi(3),\ldots\}=: \{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}.$$ We want to define a sequence not in the set $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}$. Define a sequence $g_n : \mathbb{N} \to \{7,8,9\}$ by $$g_n=\begin{cases} 7 & \text{if the $n$th term of $a_n$ is $8$} \\ 8 & \text{if the $n$th term of $a_n$ is not $8$} \end{cases}.$$ Thus, $g_1 \not= a_1, g_2 \not=a_2, ... ,g_n \not= a_n$. Thus, $(g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_n) \not\in \{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}=\psi(\mathbb{N})$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a bit like you took a correct proof but mixed some of the symbols around, so that it no longer quite makes sense. $g_n$ can't be defined in terms of $g_n$-rather, you want something like $$g_n=\left\{\begin{matrix} 7\text{ if the $n$th term of $a_n$ is $8$}\\8\text{ otherwise.}\end{matrix}\right.$$
Notice there are two changes here: you need to make sure to make $g_n$ depend on the $n$th term of $a_n$, not on the first!

Comment: I made the change from $g_n$ to $a_n$ on my post as needed. Also, I do not see it currently, but I want to know how was the $g_n$ I defined originally depending on the first term?

Comment: "if the first term of $a_n$..." is what your definition says.

Comment: I was wondering if you could clarify why the fact that $$\{g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_n\} \not\in \{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}$$ is a contradiction. Tbh, I just merely wrote that because that's what my teacher told me when I showed this to the teacher initially, but I never got to ask why. Namely, I should've established somewhere earlier in my proof that $$\{g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_n\} \in \{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}.$$

Comment: @user140170 The assumption is that $\psi$ is a bijection, and is therefore onto $B$. Yet we managed to find an element of $B$ that is not in the image of $\psi$ using the fact that $\psi$ is a bijection.

Comment: This actually isn't quite right yet. You're construction an element of $B$, so you want to say that $(g_1,g_2,...,g_n,...)$ is not in $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,...\}$. The different notation is critical! The parentheses are for a sequence, which is an element of $B$, while the brackets delimit a list of elements of $B$. So $(g_1,g_2,...)$ is like $a_1,$ not like $\{a_1,a_2,...\}$.